# What is a Pythonic way of using flags to (de)activate features in a method?

Tags: python, python-2.7

There are bits of code that I'd like to customize. Say I want to assign a bunch of student applications to a summer program to various readers (so 100 apps, 3 readers, divide them roughly evenly, etc). In some cases, I want to take reader preferences into consideration (I only want to read applications from students in California, etc.). In other cases, I don't care who they are assigned to. Right now I've got something that looks roughly like this:

```
def assign_readers(preferences_flag): 
    if preferences_flag:
        assign_readers_with_preferences()
    assign_remaining
```

I've got multiple cases of similar features throughout my code that I would like to easily turn on/off, but it doesn't look like a necessarily clean way of doing it. The same flag is sometimes used in other parts of the code, so I'm passing around these flags left and right. For example:

```
def log_reader_stats(preferences_flag, other_flag):
    if preferences_flag: 
        log_reader_stats_with_preferences()
    if other_flag:
        log_readers_stats_with_other_stuff()
    log_remaining_stats
```

What is an alternative way of doing this? Passing flags around seems repetitive and inefficient, but other than this I'm not sure how I can "toggle" such features on and off.

Below is an example of how some of the actual code being used, and how the flags come into play.

```
USE_PREF = True
USE_SPEC_GRP = True

def main(): 
    # Load and store config file information 
    fnames = {} 
    snames = {} 
    options = read_config_file()
    validate_config_params(options, fnames, snames)


    # Load the applications file
    apps = pio.file_to_frame(fnames["apps"], snames["apps"])

    # load target and max number of apps each reader can handle.
    rdr_counts = pio.file_to_frame(fnames["rdr_counts"], snames["rdr_counts"])

    # Assign applications depending on which options are enabled
    if USE_SPEC_GRP:
        assign_all_special_groups(apps, fnames["spec_grp"], snames["spec_grp"])

    if USE_PREF: 
        assign_apps_with_prefs(apps, rdr_counts, 
                                fnames["rdr_prefs"], snames["rdr_prefs"])
    assign_remaining_apps(apps, rdr_counts, fnames, snames)
```

Comment: have you considered to pass **kwargs and check the condition with kwargs.get(flag,None) ?

Comment: Personally I have no clue what “assign applications to readers” means. Perhaps if you give some actual example code, and explain what it’s supposed to do, it would be easier to suggest a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you didn't ask this, there was a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell) that warrants explanation. Whenever you find yourself using parallel data sources like `fnames` and `snames` in:

```
assign_all_special_groups(apps, fnames["spec_grp"], snames["spec_grp"])
```

you are usually making error prone code. Instead you could have

```
names['spec_grp'] = ('something', 'anotherthing')
```

which ensures that the elements of `spec_grp` always remain associated with each other. There exists a [namedtuple type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) which makes access very readable:

```
names['spec_grp'].f_thing
names['spec_grp'].s_thing
```

but without getting into that slight complexity you'll need to access them with

```
names['spec_grp'][0]
names['spec_grp'][1]
```

If I am reading your intent properly, the code above could combine these values with the option flags so that

```
 options['spec_grp'] = (fname_for_spec_grp, sname_for_spec_group)
 if options['spec_grp']:
    assign_all_special_groups(apps, options["spec_grp"][0], options["spec_grp"][1])
```

This makes initializing configuration elements that have no value to `None` important but it is also good practice.

But didn't I just make your calling code longer and harder to read? Kinda. Did it buy you flexibility, maintainability, and safety for a few extra characters? Yep. And it does turn three data structures (options, fnames, snames) into one dictionary which signals if an option is desired and if so, what its arguments are.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create a class `ReadersManager` with a property `flags`, make the functions methods of that class and access `self.flags` inside them.

Comment: Creating the flags inside a class does eliminate having to pass them around. Is there an alternative to if-statements to check on the flag activation, or is that as clean as it gets?

Comment: I can't think about something simpler than `if` for executing code depending on a condition.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to look at how others have done it, in this case in the [ConfigParser standard module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html). This uses dictionaries to store and retrieve configuration data (well actually it uses dictionaries of dictionaries but we needn't). The key point is that a dictionary can associate a name with most everything, and using data to describe the location of data is far better than hardcoding it.

In your case the dictionary

```
options = {
    'USE_SPEC_GROUP': False,
    'USE_PREF': False,
}
```

but it is a dictionary so I can add to it as needed

```
 options['available'] = False
```

or even do bulk initialization easily:

```
 options = {}
 for option in "car plane train boat".split():
     options[option] = False
```

of course accessing them in conditionals is easy

```
 if options['boat']:
     # do boat things
```

And now you have one variable to pass around that contains all the configuration data:

```
some_function(options)
```

No need to use a class when a fundamental type like `dict` is so useful on its own.